# Laravel HTTPS URL random chars?

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx

I have just set up my custom API on my sub-domain, with an SSL certificate using NGINX. Everything works just fine (get requests etc.) however, whenever I try to authenticate I receive a 401 'Invalid credentials'.

When I die and dumped `$request->all();` I figured out I suddenly have an extra GET param called 'q'? For https://api.domain.com/api/v1/login?email=test@test.com&password=test My credentials suddenly became:

```
q => email=test@test.com
password => test
```

I am absolutely baffled, does anybody have an idea whats going on? This happened when I activated my SSL cert.

I assume q is for query..
Also, here is my routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
  return 'Welcome to API';
});

/* API Version 1 */
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function() {

  Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@authenticate');

  Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function() {
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'store']]);
    Route::resource('rooms', 'RoomsController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
    Route::resource('reservations', 'ReservationsController');
    Route::resource('customers', 'CustomersController');

    Route::get('rooms/{id}/reservations', 'ReservationsController@getReservationsByRoom');
    Route::get('users/{id}/reservations', 'ReservationsController@getReservationsByUser');
    Route::get('users/{id}/customers', 'CustomersController@getCustomersByUser');
    Route::get('reservations/{id}/customer', 'CustomersController@getCustomerByReservation');

    Route::get('me', 'UsersController@getAuthenticatedUser');
    Route::get('me/reservations', 'ReservationsController@getReservationsByAuthenticatedUser');
    Route::get('me/customers', 'CustomersController@getCustomersByAuthenticatedUser');
  });
});
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. It was indeed my NGINX configuration, Laravel would not do such a thing. It is best to have at less rewrites as possible. This was in my default setting of my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$query_string;
}
```

Removing the q before query string solves of course my problem.

Thanks for all your insights

Answer (score 2):

What version of Laravel?

I have not seen this behavior (rewriting parameters); i'd be very surprised if Laravel was in fact the culprit (and a little disappointed).

If you're using Laravel 5.3 (and maybe 5.2, not sure), you can use $request->getContent() to see the entire request object as seen by Laravel. As the comment below suggests, I agree that it's not Laravel and more likely a problem with your config (especially considering it's when you enabled HTTPS).

Laravel does not handle the security layer (https), your web server does, so from Laravel's POV http === https, and it shouldn't care either way.

Comment: Yeah, it's a lot more likely this is something in the nginx config. Laravel doesn't do this.

Comment: No it's definitely not Laravel.. (I'm using 5.3 though). But I'm confused what configuration would trigger this behaviour ??? I guess tracing my steps back is my only option at the moment. @Morgan

Comment: Post your nginx config, since that is the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen in several cases that Laravel Forcing HTTPS with Mod Rewrite so you might want to take a look into that, maybe it would help.